# send message to facebook user from Messaging session after it is marked as ended?

Tags: omnichannel, workflowoutboundmessage, facebook, digital-engagement, messagingsession

using Omnichannel and messaging sessions, we can receive messages from Facebook users and respond to them all within salesforce

however, if the Facebook user (customer) logs off, the messaging session is marked as 'ended' and our salesforce agents are not able to respond/follow up with the customer.

is there a way to re-initiate or reply to conversations that are marked as 'ended' ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.messaging_agent_initiated_outbound.htm&type=5)

> Agents can proactively update customers on the status of their case by sending outbound messages. Agent-initiated outbound messaging is available for SMS channels and in beta for WhatsApp and Facebook Messenger channels.

For Facebook Messenger, this feature is in Beta and you will need to contact your Account Executive.

Once this perm is enabled, you will be able to see the "Start Conversation button" on the page using which agents can reach out to their visitors.